# How can I sum values in column based on the value in another column in Awk

Tags: awk

INPUT :

```
TT,SS,ECID,CDID,ODID,Symbol,Side,LastQty,LastPx,CumQty,AvgPx, 
"20191008-13:32:52","RO","0284","378MT","r7ot","SPD","1","100","290.67","400","290.67", 
"20191008-13:33:13","RO","02DJ","378MT","r7o","SPD","1","100","290.68","2248","290.655", 
"20191008-13:33:26","RO","FATS","378MTA","r7ot","PDF","1","100","290.92","2751","290.608",
```

Output should be :

```
SPD 200
PDF 100
```

Tried doing it using but doesn't work

```
$ awk '{a[$3]+=$4}END{for(i in a) print i,a[i]}' file
```

Comment: Your desired output looks identical to your actual output to me so - what's the problem you need help with?

Comment: Please EDIT your post and wrap samples in CODE TAGS, see this post how to use code tags on SO https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: This is an XY problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***EDIT2:*** Since OP has old `awk` where `FPAT` is not there so as per samples I added following code then.

```
awk -F, '{gsub(/\r/,"")} FNR>1{gsub(/"/,"",$8);gsub(/"/,"",$6);a[$6]+=$8} END{for(i in a){print i,a[i] | "sort -k1"}}' Input_file
```

---

---

***EDIT:*** Since OP changed Input_file completely so adding this solution now. Written and tested with GNU `awk`.

```
awk -v FPAT='[^,]*|"[^"]+"' '
gsub(/\r/,"")
FNR>1{
  gsub(/"/,"",$8)
  gsub(/"/,"",$6)
  a[$6]+=$8
}
END{
  for(i in a){
    print i,a[i]
  }
}
'   Input_file
```

OR to sort output in alphabetic order try following.

```
awk -v FPAT='[^,]*|"[^"]+"' '{gsub(/\r/,"")} FNR>1{gsub(/"/,"",$8);gsub(/"/,"",$6);a[$6]+=$8} END{for(i in a){print i,a[i] | "sort -k1"}}'  Input_file
```

---

---

You were close, problem with your approach is you haven't set field separator as `,` in your code but your Input_file has separator as `,` so it is not having `$3` at all and hence not working. Could you please try following.

```
awk -F"[[:space:]]*,[[:space:]]*" 'FNR>1{a[$3]+=$4} END{for(i in a){print i,a[i]}}' Input_file
```

PS: Thanks to oguz ismail for letting know about field separator set.